# Creating anonymous object from linq select new

Tags: c#, linq

I have a code that sort of solves my need of imitating an Include with a filter, but there is one part I don't fully understand what it does and why it's working.

I need to retrieve a customer with it's orders. In the db, the orders can be deleted so I'm only interested in bringing active orders. I disabled lazy loading, so I add the Include at the begining of the query.

```
var customer = (from c in Customers
                          .Include(c => c.Orders)
                where c.CustomerId == customerId
                select new {
                       Customer = c,
                       Orders = from o in c.Orders
                             where o.DeletedDate == null
                             select o
                       }).ToArray().Select(x => x.Customer).FirstOrDefault();
```

If at the end I'm doing the `Select(x => x.Customer)`, effectively retrieving only the Customer from the anonymous object, how is that the Orders property inside Customer is updated with the value I set in Orders in the second line of the anonymous object creation?

If I don't include the second part in the anonymous object constructor, the Customer object has no value inside Orders.

Comment: To add more information, if I do:
```
var customer = (from c in Customers
                           where c.CustomerId == customerId
                           select new {
                               Customer = c
                            }).ToArray().Select(x => x.Customer).FirstOrDefault();
```

the Customer object is returned with no orders, so what I want to understand is how the anonymous object creation works that, without me explicitely setting Orders to the new value, it updates it with the object in the secon part of the constructor

Comment: `how is that the Orders property inside Customer is updated with the value I set in Orders in the second line of the anonymous object creation?` Are you saying that `customer.Orders` does not contain orders where `DeletedDate` is not null?

Comment: `.ToArray().Select(x => x.Customer).` You don't need that `ToArray`.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting just the orders for the customer where DeletedData is null? Or does it also return deleted orders? You are telling it to include all orders for the customer, after all.

Comment: mjwillis: Indeed, the resulting Customer I get from the Select(x => x.Customer) has no deleted orders, IF I add the second line in the constructor. That's the part I don't get, but since I'm pretty new to that sort of query, I'm wondering if having teh constructor with two objects means that the second object replaces an object inside the first with the same name, or something similar

Comment: Wim ten Brink: Yes, I'm sure. If I add the lines where I filter Orders, then the orders inside Customer will be the same than the ones I filtered in the second line of the constructor

Comment: I find the whole thing really odd. Look at the SQL generated in both cases and that may answer your question. If it doesn't, please post the SQL and we can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF does not support conditional include. ObjectQuery.Include(…) will include all or nothing.

When calling ToArray(), EF tries to perform something called as Relationship fix-up. As you are loading both Customer and Orders, EF makes sure they are automatically linked, which means the matching Orders are present in Customer.Orders.

Reference links:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/10/12/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include/

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!